# triggering a click once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a chatbot's embedded code inserted into the `<body>` section of my Divi theme.
The chatbot's icon is present in every page of my website, just like I need.

In addition to the embedded code, I added the following code in the embedded code to trigger a click to open a chatbot on my website automatically:

```
document.querySelector('.lwc-chat-button').click();
```

And it's working just fine, the chat opens automatically.

However, it keeps triggering the click (opening the chat) every time I reload the page or go to a different page and this is obviously not very good.

What should I add to the embedded code in addition, so it would trigger the click only once?
And could you be specific, please? I'm a real beginner with this.
I didn't find any existing questions with the same issue, as I need to add something to the body section of my theme to make the click triggered only once (or I didn't understand enough to convert the solution over to my problem).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Devils advocate.  Why are you including that command on every page?

Comment: why not just show it, without any tricks?

Comment: It will trigger the click for as long as it is being clicked. Use an event listener with a target if you need something more specific.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like a job for [session storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage).

Simply check for a flag in `sessionStorage` first and if it is not set, trigger the click and set the flag...

```
if (!sessionStorage.getItem('clicked')) {
  sessionStorage.setItem('clicked', 'true')
  document.querySelector('.lwc-chat-button').click()
}
```

---

If you want the flag to persist longer than the current session, just switch to using [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).